# Adding bulk rows to same table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making a program for book store. Where one can add book quantity and price and store it in database. I've stored book names in one table like this:

```
+-----+-----------+
| ID  | book_name |
+-----+-----------+
| 1   | English   |
| 2   | Physics   |
| 3   | Chemstry  |
+-----+-----------+
```

And Books stock in other like this:

```
+-----+---------+---------------+------------+
| ID  | book_id | book_quantity | book_price |
+-----+---------+---------------+------------+
| 1   | 1       | 200           | 400        |
| 2   | 2       | 200           | 400        |
| 3   | 3       | 200           | 400        |
+-----+---------+---------------+------------+
```

Now the problem is I have make a program for single data insert but I dont know how to insert bulk data with this structure. HTML code is like this:

```
<form>
    English <input type="hidden" name="book_id" value="1"> <input type="text" name="book_quantity"> <input type="text" name="book_price" /> <br />
    Physics <input type="hidden" name="book_id" value="2"> <input type="text" name="book_quantity"> <input type="text" name="book_price" /> <br />
    Chemistry <input type="hidden" name="book_id" value="3"> <input type="text" name="book_quantity"> <input type="text" name="book_price" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_bulk">
</form>
```

The values of `<input name` is same, and how can I make a prefect structure, I am failing to find a proper solution for it.

Comment: i cant understand the reason behind you are giving the same name to the element . .

Comment: cuz I need arrays of `book_id`, `book_quantity` and `book_price`. Problem is solved! :)

Comment: Ohh thats great. by they way i thought you are doing this code with a static page so even i have added the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the ID to the field name, preferably as an array element. For example:

```
<input type="text" name="book_quantity[2]">
```

This would be accessible by `$_REQUEST['book_quantity'][2]` after submission.

Comment: We all have some less and some more bright moments. Let's hope the latter ones predominate. =)

Comment: I've used `$_POST['book_quantity'][2]` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

use a form like this one :

```
<form>
English <input type="text" name="book_quantity[1]"> <input type="text" name="book_price[1]" /> <br />
Physics <input type="text" name="book_quantity[2]"> <input type="text" name="book_price[2]" /> <br />
Chemistry <input type="text" name="book_quantity[3]"> <input type="text" name="book_price[3]" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_bulk">
```

this way you can retreive many values with the same name as an array. in your php code you will get this :

```
$_POST['book_quantity'][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['action'])){

    $book_Id = $_POST['book_id'];
    $book_quantity = $_POST['book_quantity'];
    $book_price = $_POST['book_price'];

    foreach($book_Id as $key => $bookid){        
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Book_Stock (book_id ,book_quantity ,book_price )  VALUES ($bookid,$book_quantity[$key],$book_price[$key])"); 
    }

}
?>
<html>
    <body> 
        <form name="bookform" id="bookform" method="POST">
            English <input type="hidden" name="book_id[]" value="1"> <input type="text" name="book_quantity[]"> <input type="text" name="book_price[]" /> <br />
            Physics <input type="hidden" name="book_id[]" value="2"> <input type="text" name="book_quantity[]"> <input type="text" name="book_price[]" /> <br />
            Chemistry <input type="hidden" name="book_id[]" value="3"> <input type="text" name="book_quantity[]"> <input type="text" name="book_price[]" /> 
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="add_bulk">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! :-)